# Center Slides with Thumbnails not working Swiper by iDangero.us

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Swiper by iDangero.us plugin. The layout I created contains 6 slider images and 6 thumbnails.

Somehow the plugin gets messed up if I make the thumbnails aligned centered. I do this by changing the `centeredSlides` var to `false`.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fa4218de/5/

Can someone help me fixing this? Or if there is any workaround ..

[Swipper API Docs](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs an answer to this. I created my own solution, by linking the thumbnails to the single swipper and rotating them with respect to the child number of thumbnails. Below is the code.

**THE JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 30,

    });

    // Make first child of div active
    $(".portfolios-thumb-wrapper .container .row div:first-child").addClass("active");


    // When click on any of the thumbnails with classname 'slide_no' it 
    // gets the child number of the div and then I just use that number
    // to rotate to that specific slide number by 'slideTo' callback
    $('.slide_no').each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var thumb = i;
            galleryTop.slideTo( thumb,1000,false );
            $('.slide_no').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
    });
});
```

**PHP with HTML (WordPress) in case you need to get and idea of markup**

```
<div class="portfolios-wrapper">
<?php   if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper gallery_top_slides">

        <?php while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>

                <?php 
                $post_id            = $post->ID;
                $permalink          = get_post_permalink( $post_id );
                $backgroundImage    = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'portfolio_background_image', true );

                ?>

                <div class="swiper-slide top_slide_<?php echo $top_counter;?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $backgroundImage; ?>');">

                    <div class="portfolio-details" style="background-color:transparent">
                        <div class="container" style="background-color:transparent">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="portfololio-thumb">
                                        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );?>
                                        <?php echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>', true );?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <div class="portfololio-excerpt">
                                        <?php echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>', true );?>
                                        <p><?php echo get_the_date( 'M Y' ); ?></p>
                                        <span class="excerpt"><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <?php $top_counter++; endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="container custom_adjust">
                <div class="swiper-button-next custom-btn-next">Next</div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev custom-btn-prev">Previous</div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php   endif; ?>
</div> 

<div class="portfolios-thumb-wrapper">
<?php   if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

            <?php while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="col-md-2 slide_no">
                        <div class="thumb_slide" style="background-image: url(' <?php echo $image[0]; ?> ')">
                        </div>
                        <div class="portfolio-title"><?php echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>', true );?> </div>
                    </div>  

            <?php $thumb_counter++; endwhile; ?>
                </div>
        </div>

<?php   endif; ?> 
</div>
```